# Crazy audio PCM file

Tags: audio, signed, pcm, audacity

I can't figure out why two non-identical raw files are exactly the same when imported into Audacity.

Let me explain, I have a 16-bit pcm file named file1.pcm, I import it into audacity with the parameter: (Signed 16-bit PCM, Little-endian, mono, 8000Hz).
Right after I export it with as parameter (raw, header-less, Signed 16 bits PCM).
Normally I should have the two identical files but not at all.
So I have two different files, but if I import them both into Audacity I have exactly the same thing

[file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7ICx.png)

[file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4j9o.png)

The two files imported in audaciy :
[Audacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZzr7.png)

If someone has an explanation, and especially how we go from one to the other.

Thanks

.G

Answer (score 0):

The problem was dither, dither was setup in audacity, when i disable it import ed and exported become exactly the same

.G

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).